# JMeter 401 Unauthorized Issue for Sharepoint 2010 application

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, jmeter, http-status-code-401

I am scripting for a Sharepoint application in its Production environment which uses NTLM Authorization. The recording is working fine, but I am facing 401:Unauthorized error while playback of the same script. Since this is an NTLM authorization application, the launch of the application redirects to the Homepage without asking for the login credentials. The first HTTP request of the script which is a GET Method throws 401 Unauthorized error. I've used HTTP Authorization Manager, HTTP Cookie Manager, HTTP Cache Manager. The same config elements are used in the scripts for UAT env which works fine and such issue is never experienced in the UAT environment.
Please feel free to suggest if you have any idea on this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP Authorization Manager should have "Domain" field populated and matching your environment for NTLM authentication along with username and password.

See [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter) guide for more details.